# How do I make volumetric grass?

Tags: c#, shaders, rendering, graphic-effects

I've been extremely interested in volumetric technology, especially for grass.

[image]

Online resources are extremely scarce on this topic.

What is the difference from creating a lot of mesh billboards?
Is this shader based technology or simply a geometry type of generator?
How do I create something like this?

Comment: Grass in the screenshot looks like a real geometry created by geometry shader.

Comment: Most volumetric grass is mainly based off of geometry shaders, as @Ocelot said. Here is a tutorial that tells how to create this effect: [How to Make Volumetric Grass in Unity](https://youtu.be/2bll1uqHYts)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Not sure what you mean by volumetric rendering of grass, can't tell the volume from the picture, but if that's the kind of thing you're talking about then you can search for "shell based fur rendering" and there'll be plenty of info on it

It's essentially a geometry shader that generates a multi-layer mesh, and samples a 3d noise texture as density for each layer, and then achieves something like "volume".

This method is equivalent to rendering the mesh many times over than a billboard, and there is an additional overhead with geometry shader, as well, as there are distortions when sampling step is too low, which I'm not sure can be solved by post-processing, such as low-sampling + blurring.

Comment: You can also accomplish an effect like this without multiple planes of geometry by raymarching in the fragment shader, which is what it looks like the image in the question is demonstrating. The lines of the bounding box are the actual geometry being rendered, and the appearance of crossed fins of geometry is created by marching the view ray along a mathematical grid, some number of steps. This does not handle glancing angles or curved surfaces well, though.